# Sorting array of entities by computed value (symfony/doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an array of entities which I want to order by country name, as translated by Intl region bundle. The country names are stored in the database as two-letter codes, and they are translated with the aid of a method of the entity.

```
class Activity {
    // ...
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2)
    */
    private $country;

    public function getCountryName()
    {
        return Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($this->country);
    }
}
```

How would I order an array of activities by country name? I can't find a way to do it with Doctrine, and `usort` doesn't work.

```
$activities = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Activity::class)->findAll();
// how do I order this by country name?
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom query in your entity Repository. Something like that...

```
public function getCountryOrderedActivity() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
                ->orderBy("c.country", "ASC")
                ->getQuery()
                ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Then in your controller do this:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Activity::class)->getCountryOrderedActivity();
```

Comment: I don't want them order by country (which is a two-letter code, like FR), but by the translation of that code (France), which is not a db field.

Comment: This is about the same... Just get the translation instead.